# Doctrine 2 - Filter loaded entities based on ACL

Tags: doctrine-orm, acl

The event listeners in Doctrine 2 are very useful. I can use them to effectively impliment ACL on entity create, update and delete. However, I can't find a way to do so for loading entities.

The postLoad event fires after an entity is loaded, and I can check the ACL in an event listener, but then what do I do? I would like to silently remove entities with ACL deny from the result set so that only those entities a user has permission to see are returned.

Within the listener I have tried `$entity = null` and `unset($entity)`, but neither of them work because UOW still holds a reference. I can use `$entitymanager->detatch($entity)` but that only removes it from the entity manager, rather than destroying the entity.

So, is there any way to do what I am trying to achive? Perhaps there is a different path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to do this is with doctrine filters. There needs to be a field in the entity you can filter on, and then away you go. No need to have a postLoad event listener. See http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/filters.html